# how to schedule a task in MVC4 C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, scheduling

I wanna create a notification system on my website?(something like stack-overflow)
How can we schedule a task for mailing the notification for users on each 24 hours?

Can we use MVC4 or we should use windows service ?

**Edit:**
My Experience with using `FluentScheduler` in 3 month within a MVC4 App .
`FluentScheduler` is easy to config and using but it doesn't run tasks any time. Sometimes run and sometimes doesn't run.
I think the best way for scheduling is `Windows Service` to ensure running a task at the specific time.

Comment: Could you please describe why rated my question -1. It was just a question. Isn't it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found this to be an awesome scheduler, [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler)

Usage:

```
// Schedule an ITask to run at an interval
    Schedule<MyTask>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(2).Seconds();
```

Comment: That dll looks awesome. I'm going to do a deep look at it.

Comment: I'm referring to the syntax, not the functionality. What's wrong with `Schedule<MyTask>(runNow: true, runEvery: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));`? Furthermore, if you look at the implementation, because of the terrible fluent syntax, it's full of race conditions and possible unintentional side effects.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the clarification. I have to disagree I think (implmentation aside) it's one of the better fluent syntax's. For the most part it is 'human' readable. 'Schedule a task to run now and every 2 seconds'. There's nothing wrong with your suggestion but I think a well thought out fluent syntax can be very helpful.

Comment: Is a fluent syntax helpful if it makes it impossible to correctly and safely start a timer? "It doesn't always work, but at least the code looks pretty..." That'd get you fired (and people dead, when you do what I do) around here.

Comment: Could anyone share any MyTask implementation, how should I define a custom task class?

Comment: I'm using it for around 6 months, but it doesn't run the task every time, do you know another reliable one

Comment: @Mohammad If it's  not suitable for your situation. Look at building a windows service.

Comment: @heads5150 you're right, `FluentScheduler` doesn't work any time, I think the best way is `Windows Service`

Answer (score 7):

You need a .Net Job Scheduler. Here is a good one: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/) scheduling service. A [.Net library](http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/13/library-net) is also available to create scheduled tasks without overhead. Errors log, Analytics, Tasks Listings and more benefits.

Disclaimer: I was among the ATrigger team. It's a freeware and I have not any commercial purpose.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you wanna use a scheduled task. Doing this in a MVC is a bad idea (mixing responsabilities) and building a windows service looks like an overkill to me (because is something doesn't need to run all the time).

Answer (score 1):

I use scheduled task of windows.

I have build a little app than enter a record in the bd, then access the website with this recordId(Guid) as a parameter.

In mvc i check if the id exist, if it exist i run tasks then delete the record in the db, if not i ignore it.

this way im able to add schedule with a param. without updating the app each time i need a new scheduled task. i just add a new task like 
"myapp.exe /MyNewTaskName"

hope this help someone ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all;

1. Add Nuget package `Install-Package FluentScheduler`
2. Add your registry class that inherit Registry and some code

```cs
// Schedule a simple task to run at a specific time
Schedule(() => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("This is from service " + DateTime.Now.Second+"\n"))
               .ToRunNow().AndEvery(2).Seconds();
```

3. Register that registry class in Application_Start of `Global.asax.cs`
   with TaskManager

```cs
TaskManager.Initialize(new Test());
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a built-in option, QueueBackgroundWorkItem. It was added in .Net 4.5.2 and [here is a guide on how to use it in MVC](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2).

In addition to previously mentioned FluentScheduler you also have [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/). And if you plan on deploying to Azure [there's a handful of different services for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs).