# asp.net mvc How to use Task Scheduler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am new to Task Scheduler for asp.net mvc. I want to perform the automatic sending mail functionality using it but i have no idea how to achive it.

please help me to carry out from it or suggest any new idea or way to perform the above task

thanks.

Comment: Please Check HERE


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620195/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-mvc4-c

Comment: @user2791307 thanks for suggestion, its mostly nearer answer of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ to achieve the same thing. I have created a Console application Which accepts some parameters and based on the parameters sent to the applications it fetches data from db and sends mail.
Task Scheduler provided by codeplex, adds tasks to your system task scheduler (you can find this in Accessories -> System Tools).
At http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ basic example is provided. Please visit documentation section if you want more sample code.

Comment: thanks for answering, the task scheduler you suggested is good for windows application but is it compatible with website which is hosted on the shared server and not have access of windows scheduler or etc..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/) scheduling service. A .Net library is also available to create scheduled tasks without overhead. Errors log, Analytics, Tasks Listings and more benefits.

You can use this kind of services in shared hosting.

**Disclaimer**: I was among the ATrigger team. It's a freeware and I have not any commercial purpose.