# Auto execute code in asp.net mvc by every month

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC application and want to execute some portion of code every month at specific time.

Is there any idea for this.

Comment: Have you looked around SO? There appears to be similar questions (e.g,. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620195/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-mvc4-c)) that might answer your question. Also, what have you tried. Please show us you've made an effort to solve your own problem. (Other asking tips may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 0):

Use the task scheduler built into Windows.  Create a cURL task that GETS/POSTS to a URL hosted by your application.
[Windows task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)