# Running a scheduled task in an ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I'm in the process of working out the architecture for a website and I've come across something I've never done before with ASP.NET. What I'd like to do is every night run a query against entities in a database table to check a date column and perform either X or Y action, depending on what the date is. Basically I want a function to be called once a night. Everything that I've searched for has lead me in a few different directions that seem either extremely complex for such a simple action, or are leaned more toward job queuing which isn't exactly what I want.

Any suggestions are welcome, just looking for the simplest approach. Thanks!

Comment: Awful solution (do not use it): Create an action in controller that do the job, then write a simple get in power-shell, run script in task schduler... But i do not recommend it, better solution is to use f.e Quartz.net that runs as f.e. as Windows Service.

Comment: Sql Server has tasks that you can schedule.  I'd recommend doing it there.

Comment: Where are you hosting your application. If you're using Azure Web Apps (I highly recommend this) you can easily attach a Web Job to your app that can be easily scheduled to run at a given interval

Comment: @JesseCarter We don't use Azure, we host our own servers.

Comment: @Chiggins Ahhh, that's a shame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to schedule a task in MVC4 C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620195/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-mvc4-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of three different options.

1. If the work you're doing is purely database related, most database platforms such as Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, etc have the ability to [schedule jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) that run at regular intervals.  These jobs could be SQL statements or stored procedures.  MS SQL Server would also let you call C# code from within a stored procedure, which would be handy.
2. Use the operating system to schedule.  Windows has [Windows Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) jobs (The `AT` command) and Unix has [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs.  You could schedule an executable to run every night, which would run C# code or SQL code.
3. Write your own scheduling service.  This service would run all the time as a Windows Service, and execute some code at a regular interval.  Check out scheduling frameworks such as [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), which can help organize some of the scheduling details.

Comment: I agree: a web server job is receive http requests and return http reponses. If you want to use it as a job scheduler, you can find a sneaky way to do it, but... you would do it wrong.
Use the right tool for the job. ASP.NET MVC (as everything running in a web server) is not.

Comment: Most of what I'm doing is wanting to check a column called finish_date and see if it's approaching a year. Once it's a week out from being a year old, email the owner and say that unless it's updated, it'll be deleted. Then on its "birthday", delete it. Not sure if your first suggestion with using a database would work with that, and I kind of would rather avoid using Windows Scheduler.

Comment: @Chiggins - You could probably implement all of that in a stored procedure.  SQL Server can send email using the [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) sproc.  The rest is just basic logic.  Then use the agent to schedule that.

Answer (score 11):

I've used [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) on a project before for doing stuff like this. Its absolutely awesome and keeps all of your code in one solution (no messing around with windows services), I highly recommend.